# Ethereum NFT options

Tags: cpp-ethereum, nft, mint

I am looking at producing a set of NFT's that are a set of 100, the item does not have an image, but is a token to run through an algorithm, I want them to be limited whole NFT's, not ERC-20s.

I am thinking there is two options:

- An ERC-1155 collection of 100 unique items with one print each
- One item with 100 prints, each print containing a unique ID

I do not mind how this is done, I am just looking for a way that I can simply generate these, sell them on open sea (or via minting) and then identify the order they were sold, i.e. first is #1.

What is the best approach here? Should I just write a mintable smart contract with ERC-1155 and then allow custom properties that store the id of each print?